# How do you determine how to split keys among reducer tasks in a MapReduce implementation?

Tags: algorithm, mapreduce, computer-science, distributed-computing

So I read the [MapReduce paper](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.824/papers/mapreduce.pdf), and am attempting to implement a simplified MapReduce according to [this](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.824/labs/lab-mr.html).

I understand that the number of mappers is determined by the input. But how do you dynamically determine the keys the reducer will operate over if you don't know the intermediate output in advance?

For example, let's say we have this MapReduce task that determines the number of a's and b's:

[image: MapReduce Example]

It's natural that there's one Reducer to count a's and one Reducer to count b's.

Mapper1 would produce this:

[image]

But for this to work I need to know advance that this is split alphabetically. What if all the keys are numeric? Heck, what if they're even emojis? How do I dynamically determine the number of reducers and the subset of data that they operate on? I feel like I'm missing something super obvious.

Comment: I think what you are missing that a reducer can handle more than 1 `key,list<value>` sets. In your example, you could have a single reducer, first operating on a's and then on b's.

Comment: @amit That makes sense, what I'm unsure of is how to arbitrarily allocate the keys that will work for any map function

Comment: what do you mean? You can always use hash(key), which decays to a simple integer (and you can use modolus on it), or am I getting this question completely wrong?

Comment: Oh my god you're right. I can't believe this didn't occur to me. It's so obvious. I'm not even new to hash functions. Thank you for the answer!